# A geometry problem involving triangles

Tags: geometry

In the figure, AE is the bisector of the exterior angle CAD meeting BC produced in E. If AB = 10 cm, AC = 6 cm and BC = 12 cm, then find the length of CE.
[image]

My Attempt: I tried to find out the existence of congruent triangles in the diagram, but couldn't find any.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are AC and BC Perpendicular .

Comment: Definitely not. (Evident from the given lengths of AB, BC and CA)

Comment: from cosine theorem you can find all angles from triangle $ABC$ and solve your OP

Comment: If $BC=8$, $\Delta ABC$ would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively: Continue the line $D$ until $F$ and connect $F$ with $E$ so that $AC=AD$.

Note that $\Delta ACE$ is equal to $\Delta ADE$, because two sides and the angle between them are equal. It implies the line $AE$ is a bisector in $\Delta BDE$.

Using the property of bisector:
$$\frac{AB}{BE}=\frac{AD}{DE} \Rightarrow \frac{10}{12+CE}=\frac{6}{CE} \Rightarrow CE=18.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : The cosine law of triangles will definitely solve the problem but that may lead to boring calculations.

You can construct congruent triangles.

Draw a line passing point E and parallel to AC, intersecting AB at F. Now ABC is congruent to FBE, and AF=EF, so you can find the length of AF by solving the equation w.r.t AF.

> $\frac{BA}{BA+AF}=\frac{AC}{EF}=\frac{AC}{AF}$

Continue the reasoning and you can find the length of CE.

Answer (score 1):

Let $CE=x$.

Hence, by bisector theorem we obtain:
$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BE}{EC}$$ or
$$\frac{10}{6}=\frac{x+12}{x}$$ or
$$\frac{5}{3}=1+\frac{12}{x}$$ or
$$\frac{12}{x}=\frac{2}{3}$$ or
$$x=18$$.